# A tecla espaço também se torna um caractere? LENGHT

Tags: javascript, html5

A tecla espaço também se torna um caractere?

Meu problema é que mesmo se na input `#userChat` só houver a tecla espaço ele mesmo assim da o `alert()`, e isso acaba sendo um grande problema..

Teclas: Espaço e Quebra de linha. Preciso que só posso dar um `alert` se realmente tiver escrito algo, Caracteres, Letras, números, símbolos, sás coisas.

```
$('.butSend').click(function() {
    var mensagem = $("#userChat").val();
    var n = mensagem.length;
    if(n > 0){ 
        alert(mensagem);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim o espaço é um carácter "em branco", ou seja um espaço. Você pode contornar esse tipo de problema fazendo um [`trim`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) na *string*:

```js
$('.butSend').click(function() {
    var mensagem = $("#userChat").val().trim();
    var n = mensagem.length;
    if(n > 0){ 
        alert(mensagem);
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="userChat"> <button class="butSend">Enviar</button>
```

A [função `trim`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) remove todos os espaços em branco do começo e final da *string* e caso ela seja feita apenas de  (espaços), então ficará vazia.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer o seguinte:

```
if($("#userChat").val().replace(/ /g,'')!=""){
     alert(mensagem);
}
```

nesse caso usei o replace para remover os caracteres em branco

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. ;)

Comment: Nesse caso acho que ele não removeria quebras de linha, correto?